# How to have different .htaccess for different domains/request urls?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, development-environment, production-environment

I work as a web developer, creating custom websites for customers. My `.htaccess` files are generally very simple. I generally only do 2 things:

1. Create a custom ErrorDocument for 404 errors
2. Redirect the `/upload` directory to `/admin/upload` to simplify some shared code between the public website and the admin system

I have everything working okay, other than one slight annoyance I'm wondering if anything can be done about. I'm using php, and I try to design the websites in a modular fashion, so that it doesn't matter whether the code is hosted at "example.com/" (the real domain), "localhost/exampleproject2" (on my development machine), or "mycompanywebsite.com/example.com" (Where we host a "beta" version for the customer to view when we get to that point in development).

From the PHP side of things, I have no issues here. But so far as Apache is concerned, I have to create 3 slightly different `.htaccess` files for each of those domains:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Redirect 301 /upload /admin/upload
```

```
ErrorDocument 404 /exampleproject2/404.php

Redirect 301 /exampleproject2/upload /exampleproject2/admin/upload
```

```
ErrorDocument 404 /example.com/404.php

Redirect 301 /example.com/upload /example.com/admin/upload
```

Obviously this is not a huge deal, but it is a bit annoying. Mostly when I or someone else transfers files over FTP and accidentally overwrites the `.htaccess` from one environment with it's counterpart from another environment, and the site breaks. Also it means I can't include `.htaccess` in my git repository without possibly breaking things.

From my testing, relative urls don't seem to work at all. I think maybe Apache just doesn't support relative urls in `.thaccess` files for `Redirect`s and `ErrorDocument`s. At least that's the way it seems. I get a server error when I try.

I'd like a way to have a single `.htaccess` file I can share between all 3 environments and include in the git repository. If anyone knows a good way to accomplish this that would be awesome. Solutions don't have to use `.htaccess`, I'm open to any solution that makes my code less dependent on absolute paths or urls.

Comment: I don’t think relative URL paths won’t work for ErrorDocument per se, but for Redirect they definitively won’t, that does prefix-based matching on the requested URL. But you could use a RewriteRule to do those redirects instead.

Comment: In general though, I have to say I am not a big fan of having development systems set up in ways that significantly differ from the live systems - that can always lead to unexpected problems, and the time to debug those, can be spent better on actual development. I would set up proper VirtualHosts for these projects, instead of switching to sub-folders. `localhost/exampleproject2` would be `exampleproject2.local` in my setups, and `mycompanywebsite.com/example.com` would rather be `beta.example.com` or something like that.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, doing something like `exampleproject2.local` would require either modifying the hosts file on any machine on the LAN that needs to view the development copy of the site, or having and configuring a local DNS server. Although I do agree, having the developments and production environments match would be ideal, my intent in doing this is trying to avoid unnecessary complexity.

Comment: With your approach, wouldn’t you just be adding complexity in a different place though? Anyway, if all your systems use Apache 2.4, I suppose this could relatively easy be done, by wrapping all your ErrorDocuments and Redirects into an IF-condition that checks the request host name and/or requested path prefix, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples